# Symfony 4 webpack sass loader

Tags: symfony, webpack, symfony4

I'm new to webpack technology. I have folder structure like this

[image]

And I need to compile all scss to css with preserved subfolders in page directory. In this example I need to have css file in /public/build/assets/scss/page/home/index.css

This is my webpack.config.js file

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
// directory where compiled assets will be stored
.setOutputPath('public/build/')
// public path used by the web server to access the output path
.setPublicPath('/build')
// only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
//.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

/*
 * ENTRY CONFIG
 *
 * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
 * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
 *
 * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
 * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if you JavaScript imports CSS.
 */
.createSharedEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
.addEntry('page', './assets/js/page.js')
//.addEntry('page2', './assets/js/page2.js')

/*
 * FEATURE CONFIG
 *
 * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
 * list of features, see:
 * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
 */
.cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
.enableBuildNotifications()
.enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
// enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
.enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

// enables Sass/SCSS support
.enableSassLoader(function(options) {
    // https://github.com/sass/node-sass#options
    // options.includePaths = [...]
})

.autoProvidejQuery()

.enablePostCssLoader()

.configureFilenames({
    images: '[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]',
    fonts:  '[path][name].[ext]'
})

// uncomment if you use TypeScript
//.enableTypeScriptLoader()

// uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
//.autoProvidejQuery()
;

const config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
config.watchOptions = {
    poll: true,
};

module.exports = config;
```

And my page.js where I scan all files in this folder.

```
const sassContext = require.context('../scss/page', true, /\.(scss)$/);
sassContext.keys().forEach(sassContext);
```

But all files are generate in /public/build/assets/page.css. You know how to do it correctly?

**EDIT(1)**

I remove addEntry(page.js) from webpack.config.js and load stylesheets in this way

```
var scssFile = walkSync(__dirname + '/assets/scss/page/');

scssFile.forEach(function(value) {
    var mapReplace = {
       "/scss":"/css",
       ".scss":""
    };
    var input  = value.replace(/\/scss|\.scss/gi, function(matched){
        return mapReplace[matched];
    }); 
    var output = '.' + value;
    Encore.addStyleEntry(input,output);
});
```

WalkSync is a function which recursive scanning directory and return array of full file path. Do you think this is a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want control result files structure ?

You'll quickly see that webpack does a pretty good job by himself.
If you're worried about image file referenced in your css files, those will be copied in your build folder on webpack compilation.

Also, what exactly does your page.js do ? You shouldn't need any additional scripts to convert your sass files into CSS.

**Edit :**

The way webpack works is that you "pack" a group of files (stylesheets and js) toghether.

I handle my application by creating an "app" pack with all files global to the whole website and then create individual files for each page that holds only the files they need. But in the end, you will have only one "app" file and one "page" file.

Here is an example of configuration :

```
.addEntry(
        'app',
        [
            './assets/scss/app.scss',

            './assets/js/app.js'
            './assets/js/jquery.js',
        ]
    )

.addEntry(
        'dashboard',
        [
            './assets/scss/pages/dashboard.scss'
        ]
    )
```

Then in your page you call them like this :

```
<link href="{{ asset('build/app.css') }}" />
<link href="{{ asset('build/dashboard.css') }}" />

<script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}></script>
```

Comment: I want control result files structure because i don't need to load all stylesheets on all pages.

Comment: I almost meant it but this solution has a disadvantage. If you have a lot of pages then you will have to manually add each one. I was thinking about something that automates the whole process

Comment: If you load your stylesheets one by one, this will lead to performances issues for users navigating your pages. Stylesheets and JavaScript files should always be agregated and minified so the users has to load as few of them as possible.

If you have so much stylesheets that it becomes an issue, there's probably something wrong in your project structure. You need to identify your pages with similar needs and group the files they have in common. Even if some of those pages don't require one or two files, you can leave them together as they will be cached by the navigator.

Comment: I dont have performances issues because i have 2 stylesheets on every page. The general and the individual for the site. Both are minified. Script generate only a folder structure and i decide which is attached by add link href on page "home" like this <link href="{{ asset('build/css/page/home/index.css') }}" /> and page "contact" like this <link href="{{ asset('build/css/page/contact/index.css') }}" />

Comment: Are you using an external library for minifying your assets? Because this is basically what webpack does: it compiles, regroups and minifies your assets. All you have to do is regroup the assets that belong to a specific section of your website, call add entry, give an identifier then add all your css, sass, less, javascript or even typscript files.

You're going to run into issues if you try to control the way your build folder behaves.

Comment: No i dont have any external library to do that.